# Add information to one table from table contains duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

In Table_1, (ID, Name) pairs can repeat and have any combination
Table_1:

| ID | Name | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 34 | 45 |
| 1 | John | 15 | 78 |
| 2 | Randy | 67 | 12 |
| 2 | Randy | 40 | 46 |
| 1 | Randy | 23 | 85 |
| 2 | Holmes | 10 | 100 |

I want to find all information for all unique pairs. So the output should be:

| ID | Name | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 34 | 45 |
| 2 | Randy | 67 | 12 |
| 1 | Randy | 23 | 85 |
| 2 | Holmes | 10 | 100 |

When I do `SELECT DISTINCT(ID, Name)` I get the unique pairs correctly. But how do I add value1, value2 columns to this. Because adding value1, value2 causes the pairs to repeat.

Comment: What is the logic for which record of a given pair (or more) to retain?  It isn't clear from your description.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen any, it doesn't matter. All I want are unique (id,name) pairs with any value1,value2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `DISTINCT ON` here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID, Name) *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID, Name;
```

### Demo

This will arbitrarily return one record from each `(ID, Name)` combination.  Note that if you wanted to choose which of the duplicate pair (or more) records gets retained, you could add another level to the `ORDER BY` clause.  For example, to choose the duplicate record with the highest `Value2` value, you could use:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID, Name) *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID, Name, Value2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

try row_number and partition by.

```
SELECT * 

FROM   (
select *,
row_number() over(partition by Name order by Name desc) rn 
from Table_1) as a

where rn = 1;
```